# Searching for matching cells and copying row data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to Visual Basic, so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I have two excel documents, one with a list of company names and their corresponding identifying numbers (about 4000 in total). In a separate document, I have a list of people and who they work for (these are the same companies from the first document, but sometimes there will be more than one row per company, since we work with more than one person from that company). There are about 7000 entries here. I want to transfer all of the company ID numbers into the document with all of the company personnel. I have the concept for the code down, but unfortunately, I don't know enough about Excel VBA syntax to write this. I wrote some code, but it doesnt work and I don't know why.

```
Sub Firm_Number_Transfer()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    row = 1
    oldRow = 1

    For i = Workbooks("PM Firm Contacts - Step 2 - REVIEWED").Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells("B1") To Workbooks("PM Firm Contacts - Step 2 - REVIEWED").Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells("B7122") Step 1
        row = row + 1
        For x = Workbooks("PM Firms - Step 1 - REVEIWED").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("B2") To Workbooks("PM Firms - Step 1 - REVEIWED").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("B4843") Step 1
            oldRow = oldRow + 1
            If i = x Then
                Workbooks("PM Firm Contacts - Step 2 - REVIEWED").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, 1) = Workbooks("PM Firm Contacts - Step 2 - REVIEWED").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(oldRow, 1)
                found = True
            End If
        Next x
        found = False
        oldRow = 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I should also add that the table is set up in such a way that the companies are on the right and the company numbers are on the left. From what I understand, `VLOOKUP()` only works if the companies are on the left and the company numbers i'm copying are on the right. Otherwise `VLOOKUP()` would be what I would use.

Comment: You need to add some error trapping and should probably try to step through the code to see where the problem happens.

Comment: It gives me a "subscript out of range error" and highlights the first for statment when I run it.

Comment: You can try with a Vlookup assuming all company names in the people's workbook matches up with your company ID workbook and there are no duplicates in the company ID workbook.

Comment: You can't iterate that For loop the way it is set up. Give me a few minutes and I'll post an answer to help get you started

Comment: Are you familiar with the VLOOKUP() function? You can look up the company ID number for each person's company a lot easier that way.

Comment: My guess is you're not looping correctly.  Do you want to loop from row 1 to row 7122?  Or do you have values in cell B1 and B7122 that dictate what the looping start and end should be?  Again, just a guess, you want to loop from row 2 to 7122, correct?

Comment: Additionally, your "For" statement is not quite correct.
I'm assuming you're trying to loop from cell [B1] to cell [B7122].
Your for statement should be:
For i = 1 to 7122

Comment: I'm looping from B2 to B7122 (that's where the company names are) The cells where the firm numbers go are in column A

Comment: The `for` statement takes only integers, it doesn't take cells, so it's just not doing what you want.
You must do loops in another way, I believe `rwisch45` answer gives a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid code using a `VLOOKUP` formula:

In the personel sheet, add in the destination column:

```
= VLOOKUP(PARAM1, PARAM2, Param3)
```

Where:

Param1 - The cell in the personel sheet containing company name

Param2 - The range in the company sheet (from colum to column, like A:C), from the column containing company names to the column containind their IDs

Param3 - the index of the column containin the IDs related to the names (if IDs are in column C, for example, and names in Column A, the index is 3 - third column)

You put that formula and drag it down to all personel.

Other option using `Index` and `Match`

```
= index(IDColumn; match(CellWithCompanyNameInPersonelSheet; CompanyNameColumn; 0))
```

Where you have to use a column, place something like "B:B" for column "B".

Comment: Yes, I know about VLOOKUP(), but it would be looking in a separate document for the data, which I don't think you can do.

Comment: Also, I'm searching on the right side of the table, and copying the data on the left. It seems as though VLOOKUP only searches on the left and copies data on the right.

Comment: @bspymaster You should be able to, unless your company uses Citrix - has excel on a server - that can sometimes cause problems with referencing another excel file. But in any case you can just copy and paste the data into the other workbook easy enough. VLOOKUP is going to be the way you want to go.

Comment: `INDEX` and `MATCH` and its totally possible to reference other workbooks

Comment: How would I use `INDEX` and `MATCH` though? I've never heard of either of those, and I'm confused how I would use them. I'd assume something like `INDEX(MATCH())` but I don't know what data to put in.

Comment: See Update to Index Match

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. Was the statement within the If block a typo? I think you might have meant to copy from one workbook/worksheet to the other (not from the same one)?

```
Sub Firm_Number_Transfer()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim oldRow As Integer
        Dim found As Boolean
        Dim xlBook As Workbook, xlBook2 As Workbook
        Dim xlSheet As Worksheet, xlSheet2 As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rng2 As Range, cell2 As Range

    xlBook2 = Workbooks("PM Firms - Step 1 - REVEIWED")
    xlSheet2 = xlBook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng2 = xlSheet2.Range("B2:B4843")

    xlBook = Workbooks("PM Firm Contacts - Step 2 - REVIEWED")
    xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = xlSheet.Range("B1:B7122")

    row = 1
    oldRow = 1

    For Each cell In rng
        row = row + 1
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            oldRow = oldRow + 1
            If cell.Value2 = cell2.Value2 Then
                xlSheet.Cells(row, 1) = xlSheet.Cells(oldRow, 1)
                found = True
            End If

        Next
        found = False
        oldRow = 1

    Next

End Sub
```